# Changing an immutable object F#

Tags: json, f#, type-providers, f#-data

I think the title of this is wrong but can't create a title that reflects, in the abstract, what I want to achieve.

I am writing a function which calls a service and retrieves data as a JSON string.  The function parses the string with a [JSON type provider](http://fsharp.github.io/FSharp.Data/library/JsonProvider.html).  Under certain conditions I want to amend properties on that JSON object and then return the string of the amended object. So if the response from the call was

```
{"property1" : "value1","property2" : "value2", "property3": "value3" }
```

I want to change property3 to a new value and then return the JSON string.

If the JsonProvider was mutable this would be an exercise like:

```
type JsonResponse = 
        JsonProvider<""" {"property1" : "value1", 
                          "property2" : "value2",
                          "property3": "value3" } """>

let jsonResponse = JsonResponse.Parse(response)
jsonResponse.Property3 <- "new value"
jsonResponse.ToString()
```

However, this does not work as the property cannot be set.  I am trying to ascertain the best way to resolve this. I am quite happy to initialise a new object based on the original response but with amended parameters but I am not sure if there is an easy way to achieve this.

For reference, the JSON object is much more involved than the flat example given and contains a deep hierarchy.

Comment: If the type of `jsonResponse` was a record, you could do `{ jsonRespose with Property3 = "new value" }`. But that doesn't seem to work.

Comment: unfortunately, type providers are not currently able to create record types.

Comment: https://github.com/fsharp/FSharp.Data/issues/178

Answer (score 7):

Yes, you would need to create a new object, changing the bits you want and using the existing object's values for the rest.  We added write APIs for both the XML and JSON type providers a while back.  You will notice the types representing your JSON have constructors on them.  You can see an example of this in use at the bottom of [this link](http://fsharp.github.io/FSharp.Data/library/JsonProvider.html)

Comment: Thanks for this answer.  I have experimented with this and the only way I can make this work is by specifying all the properties of the JSON as arguments in the constructor.  This works for the example I have given let newThing = JsonResponse.Example("value2", "value3", "value3") but for a large object graph this is not really practical.  Have you any insight how you could do this in a more "picky" manner, ie only amending specific properties of the old object into the new object.  The properties I want to set on the new object are a couple of layers deep within the hierarchy.

Comment: The write APIs are relatively new, we added full constructor support, and the ability to copy from other JsonValue objects (the underlying type erased down to) - this lets you copy data between JSON type provider types that share identical sub-types nested within them.  For what you want, it would probably need some new support in the type provider.  I agree this would be useful, you should perhaps open an issue in the FSharp.Data github for this. (or go for it yourself!)

Comment: Apparently it's currently not possible: https://github.com/fsharp/FSharp.Data/issues/914#issuecomment-189069108