# How do I edit an XML file using type providers?

Tags: f#, type-providers

I understand how to retrieve data from an XML source using type providers. However, I need to then modify a particular part of the XML and save it to disk. I have tried assigning a value to the node using `<-` but the property is read-only.

For example:

```
let doc = MyXml.load fileName
doc.ItemId.Id <- "newId" // doesn't work
doc |> saveXml
```

There is a [similar question for JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24447305/changing-an-immutable-object-f) where the suggestion is to create a new object, but this is specifically for XML.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

While researching my question I found that you can use the `.XElement` accessor to get a reference to a mutable `XElement` object. Thus a solution is:

```
let doc = MyXml.load fileName
doc.ItemId.XElement.Element(XName.Get "Id").Value <- "newId" // tada
doc.XDocument.Save(...)
```

Note that you have to use the `.XElement` accessor on the *parent* if you're modifying a leaf node. This is because the leaf node's type is a primitive and doesn't have an `.XElement` accessor of its own. A slight shame, but I suppose it makes life easier on the other side when you want read-only access to the value.