# Merging values from a CSV-file into a JSON structure

Tags: f#, f#-data

I have a pretty big JSON structure that I need to update with values from a CSV file.

Each row in the CSV file contains the id of the object to update and the field name. The values that I want to update can be nested.

Reading the JSON data with JsonTypeProvider is easy, but how can I merge the values before writing them to file?

I don't want to create a type that matches the JSON structure and deserialize it, because it contains so many values that I'm not interested in, but I need them all to be in the final result.

This is my program:

```
type JsonFile = JsonProvider<"./myjson.json">
type CsvFile = CsvProvider<"./texts.csv">

[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv =  

    let jsonValues = JsonFile .GetSample().Result

    let texts = CsvFile.GetSample().Rows

    let result =
        jsonValues
        |> Seq.map(fun v ->

            // I would like to merge values here
            let texts = texts |> Seq.filter(fun t -> t.Id = string v.Id)
            let description = texts |> Seq.tryFind (fun t -> t.FieldName = "Description")

            if description.IsSome then
                v.Description.["en"] <- description.Value.En // This doesn't work of course, just an example of what I would like to do
                v.Description.["no"] <- description.Value.No

            // etc etc

            v.JsonValue                  
        )
        |> Seq.map(fun json -> json.ToString(JsonSaveOptions.DisableFormatting))
        |> String.concat "\n"



    let fileName = "./mergedvalues.ndjson"

    File.WriteAllText(fileName,
                      result,
                      System.Text.Encoding.UTF8)

    0
```

How can I update the values of the JSON file?

I see that the JsonTypeProvider might not be appropriate to do this sort of thing, I'm open to any suggestion.

**Update:**

So I found out I could create new values like this:

```
let newDescription =
     JsonFile.Description(``type`` = v.Type,
                           no = v.Description.No,
                           en = Some "my new value",
                           fr = v.Description.Fr,
                           de = v.Description.De,
                           nl = v.Description.Nl)
```

My problem is that some of my records have **a lot** of fields, so using the constructor like this is really inconvenient, and sometimes even hard to get right. Is there any way I can use my existing `JsonProvider<...>` value to instantiate the type, and update only the fields I would like to update?

Comment: Why this does not work `v.Description.["en"] <- description.Value.En`?

Comment: The property is not mutable

Comment: It seems your problem has not been solved: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24447305/changing-an-immutable-object-f

Comment: :( Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 1):

For this case, you should consider using JsonValue Properties property which is basically a string * JsonValue array.

Then you can match properties defined in your csv and update deeper and deeper (fold) your jsonvalue and injecting it to the main constructor (Root if you don't have redefined it).